# Android GIF Support -- React Native 0.50

Tags: android, react-native, gif, animated-gif

I have included a gif image in react native project and its working perfectly in IOS without any issues.

my Js file

```
<Image
source={require("../resources/toolbar/transaction_success.gif")}
                            style={styles.logo}
                    />
```

For android, I came across a library(FRESCO) which supports gif in android.

> compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.8.1'

Android build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile project(':react-native-sensitive-info')
compile project(':react-native-i18n')
compile project(':react-native-device-info')
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.8.1'
}
```

Its not displaying gif after including this library.

I have tried some other versions of same library but its not working.

```
 compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:0.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:0.12.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:0.14.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:0.14.1'
```

If I use these below two lines application closes without any error.

```
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.8.1'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.8.1'
```

Please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: You can use react-native-fast-image to play GIF's.

Comment: I'm getting error-- Native Component for fast image view does not exist on using React-native-fast-image-view

Comment: https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image react-native-fast-image not React-native-fast-image-view

Comment: yes. same one. Its good you share code as answer.

Comment: have you linked the library ?

Comment: react-native link react-native-fast-image have you performed this step?

Comment: Linked. Getting error --Native component for fast image view does not exist

Comment: Are you making project using Expo or CRNA?

Comment: React-native init ProjectName

Comment: Please also check in your android files whether your project is successfully linked or not.Sometimes react native link does not work as expected.

Comment: everything's fine. Not working.

Comment: `My app is getting crashed after including this library` What does that mean? Please update your question with more specific details.

Comment: updated exactly. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in this way I resolved this.

1) Removed all existing  Fresco dependencies like fresco.fresco , animated.gif etc..

2). Tried React-native-fast image based on community suggestions.Linked to both ios and android platforms. Getting error --Native component for fast image view does not exist. Dropped plan of using this npm library.

3) Added only below line  to android/build-gradle .

> compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0'

4)Tap Sync Now option in android studio so that it will reflect grade changes.

5) Clean Project.

6) Rebuild Project.

you can take both debug and release builds.

It works fine.

Comment: I tried this...it does not work. I think I will use different approach and use another package instead of GIF to show a series of photos

Comment: Did that but it did not help. I've added `compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0'` and `compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0'` but the behavior remain as described

Answer (score 1):

Add in your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.9.0'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.9.0'
```